# Imgur server-to-server request on-behalf of user?

Tags: imgur

I am currently designing a solution for a client and they which to create albums of images and display them on the website. The crux is that ideally we want to offload the hosting of the images to a third-party service (i.e. imgur). Is it possible with the imgur API to make requests on-behalf of a user without explicit (e.g. redirect with login) user consent?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this is not possible. If anyone is looking for a similar solution, none of the big players allow this type of integration. I ended up using a custom solution.